# tree reconstruction with characters

Tags: tree, graph-algorithm, depth-first-search

We are given a tree consisting of N vertices, rooted at vertex 1. Each vertex consists of a lowercase English alphabet as a node value.

If the ancestor node has the same node value as that of any vertex, then that ancestor node is considered as its valid parent vertex.

Our task is to detach all the nodes from the tree and attach them to any of the valid parent vertices (in the initial tree) and print the count of no of nodes in the subtree of each node.

This question is extension of this question: https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/graphs/depth-first-search/practice-problems/algorithm/tree-recreation-88871e63/

constarints:

1<=t<=10

1<=N<=100000

a<=val[i]<=z

My approach:

Using stack, i am finding first the no of connected components formed after the recreation of tree. I want to further use my code to count no of subtree of each node. Can anyone share his approach?

```
  My code:
  
  #include<bits/stdc++.h>
 using namespace std;
  typedef long long ll;
typedef unsigned long long ull;
 #define M 1000000007
 #define ff first.first
 #define fs first.second
 #define sf second.first
 #define ss second.second
 #define f first
 #define s second
 #define inf 9000000000000000000
 vector<ll> adj[100002];
ll val[100002],compo;
stack<ll> st[26];
 ll cnt[26];
 ll arr[100002];

void dfs(ll x, ll par)
{
 if(st[val[x]].empty())
{
//     cout << x << " ";
    compo++;
}
st[val[x]].push(x);

for(auto node: adj[x])
{
    if(node==par)
    {
        continue;
    }      
    dfs(node, x);   

}
    
st[val[x]].pop();
}

int main()
{
ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
cin.tie(NULL); 
cout.tie(NULL);
ll t;
cin>>t;
while(t--)
{
    memset(cnt,0,sizeof(cnt));
    memset(arr,0,sizeof(arr));
    ll n,i;
    char s;
    compo = 0;
    cin>>n;
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
        adj[i].clear();

    for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        cin>>s;
        val[i] = s - 'a';
    }
    for(i=1; i<n; i++)
    {
        ll a,b;
        cin>>a>>b;
        adj[a].push_back(b);
        adj[b].push_back(a);
    }

    dfs(1,0);
    cout<<compo<<"\n";
   
    
}

return 0;
}
```

check my this implementation also: https://pastebin.com/XTPQ1pfJ

Comment: @trincot why so complicated ?

Comment: @trincot we have to find the count of nodes in the subtree  of each node after performing detachment .That is why

Comment: @trincot suupose this case 
7
a a a b b b a
(1 2)
(1 3)
(2 4)
(2 5)
(3 6)
(6 7) .. what should  the answer for this?

Comment: why there is no any reply?

Comment: I have pasted one new implementation of my approach.Please check

Comment: why i am not getting replies to my post?